# VB.NET - Working with tab delimited text file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I need help with how to work on text file (like database).

I create excel GUI (with macro's), that search imputed string in sheets with lots of data and display entire row with matching string (for people with installed MS office)

Now I must create alternative VB.Net application working only on tab delimited text files (without ADO.Net) for people who haven't installed MS office, and I don't know how start to work with it.

- import them? if yes, then how.
- working directly on them? if yes, then how.

My text files is exported excels files/sheets to tab delimited .txt, with loots of columns (100+) with headers, and lots of rows 500+

need help :)
thx

Comment: I search DataTable solutions but can't find how to import text file with headers, only how to manually add/create headers and rows with data

Comment: http://bit.ly/1NK0qq0

Comment: [Parsing Text Files with the TextFieldParser Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x710fk43.aspx)

Comment: ... and *lots of rows* start at 50k+

Comment: You can also import to typed data using OleDB

Comment: if you are using macros, you are not using VB.NET

Comment: @Plutonix I using macros in excel, but now, I need replace it with Windows GUI, for users who don't have installed MS Office.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the headers from the first line of the file then do this ...

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dt = New DataTable

    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt")

    Dim headers = lines(0).Split(vbTab)
    For Each header In headers
        dt.Columns.Add(header)
    Next

    For Each line In lines.Skip(1)
        Dim parts = line.Split(vbTab)
        dt.Rows.Add(parts)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: great thx for showing how I can approach it, without using ADO.Net